# One WP Database outside localhost and two connections

Tags: database, htaccess, customization

I would like to ask for help with this problem. I have two places where I have the same WP.

1) Test site - own domain, hosting and DB
- here is stored database, so siteurl is here, example: test.com and everything in wordpress is using this domain

2) Localhost development
- Problem: I want to use same database from test site, but url in .htaccess will be different same as in the DB.

Is there any possibility to use database from test site on localhost in order to maintain everything function correctly? I would like to create posts on test site, not on localhost. Localhost is only for webdesign development.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is this a wordpress specific question? just connect to your test DB from you local host WP.

Comment: Very specific. Because when i connect it, site_url says "test.com" not localhost, so every article and page will not be working on localhost, but on test.com

Comment: In your local hosts file define test.com to point to 127.0.0.1 and edit your server configuration so it will handle it properly

Comment: Ok. You have my attention, can you give me an example pls?